# what are the cons of converting plastic to fuel

Tags: polymers, plastics, fuel

I have been trying to read how to fix plastic problems, there seems to be 3 outstanding solutions

1. Re-use
2. Recycle
3. Decompose to Fuel

Recycling is expensive, requires lots of water and the quality degrades on each recycle. I can partially understand why companies won't recycle

However I am unable to understand why would we not decompose to fuel. I have tried reading following articles:

- [Can plastic be used as fuel for vehicles?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70276/can-plastic-be-used-as-fuel-for-vehicles/70280#70280)
- https://www.power-technology.com/comment/plastic-to-fuel/
- http://www.anthropocenemagazine.org/2019/02/new-technique-converts-plastic-waste-to-fuel/
- http://www.deccanchronicle.com/science/science/180717/hyderabad-techie-recycles-plastics-into-fuel.html

It seems the primary way is `Anhydrous pyrolysis` requires no water, limited sorting and seems to convert 80% of plastic to fuel. I am unable to understand why would everybody not do this ? seems a viable solution and a profitable business

Comment: Perhaps better is to use plastics as fuel directly, in high capacity, high temperature facilities, providing electricity or hot water.

Comment: Following the previous comment, what kind of "fuel" are you looking for? Not all fuels are made equal. Wood is useful as a fuel, but so is ethanol.

Comment: @Poutnik using plastics as fuel directly has more pollution impact than converting and using it.

Comment: @BuckThorn Looking at petroleum fuel - diesel, petrol etc

Comment: @Gaurav Shah I would say the opposite. There is environmental impact of conversion and small local device combustion has worse parameters.

Comment: makes sense that way. Thanks @Poutnik